# In Xcode 7, how to delete AppIDs that a normal AppleID create?

Tags: ios, xcode7

To debug my app, I use Xcode 7 with my Apple ID (not a developer) to create AppIds, like this:

[image: pic1]

Now I have a problem. My company has a company developer. I want to submit my app to when I use it to create the same AppIDs. That can't proceed. It has a conflict. But when I login Apple Developer Center, I must to enroll like below. I want to delete the AppIDs that my Apple ID created. How to resolve this problem?

[image: pic2]